# Custom deserialization of List using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to write a custom deserializer in order to trim down a big set of data I receive from somewhere else. I return a List of custom objects from the deserializer.

My question is, how do I do that, if this is my custom deserializer :

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<CustomClass>> { ... }
```

I certainly can't do this :

```
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(List<CustomClass>.class, new MyCustomDeserializer());
```

Will something like this work ?

```
final List<CustomClass> response = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(stringBean, CustomClass[].class));
```

If this indeed works, I find it a bit confusing and "dangerous" ? Isn't the deserialization done inside the asList method invocation ? So it basically maps a List to an array[] ?

I learned about TypeReference so I can probably use that like so :

```
objectMapper.readValue(stringBean, new TypeReference<List<CustomClass>>(){});
```

but I heard it is slower.

I also don't want to create a container for the list, and return that in the deserialization because that means it will be wrapped in another json object, and I simply want my endpoint to produce something like :

```
[{object1}, {object2}]

// instead of

{"Output" : [{object1}, {object2}]}
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that I have misinterpreted how jackson is using my deserializer in both cases :

```
final List<CustomClass> response = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(stringBean, CustomClass[].class));
// or
objectMapper.readValue(stringBean, new TypeReference<List<CustomClass>>(){});
```

It looks like the deserializer is called twice, once for each object in the array. I thought that the entire array would be considered as a whole. To clear the confusion, here is what I mean:

The json I receive and try to deserialize looks like so :

```
[
  {
    "Data" : {
      "id" : "someId",
      "otherThing" : "someOtherThing"
    },
    "Message" : "OK"
  },
  {
    "Data" : null,
    "Message" : "Object not found for id blabla"
  }
]
```

and so I though this is what I would have inside my deserializer, but as I said before it seems that i actually get each "entry" from that array and call it multiple times.

Comment: Also need to state that i registered the deserializer on the bean using the @JsonDeserializer annotation.

Comment: Use the `ObjectMapper`'s `TypeFactory`; it allows you to create type descriptions like you want, ie, "a List of CustomClass". Also, please mention the version of Jackson you are using.

Comment: I'm using jackson 2.4 version. Can  you provide me with some materials in using the type factory method ? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, If you registered your custom deserializer using annotation on the bean `CustomClass` then the deserializer should handle one instance of `CustomClass` and not a collection and thus should be defined:

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<CustomClass> {
        @Override
        public CustomClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

and now you can use Jackson's type factory to pass the mapper the required type information

```
JavaType customClassCollection = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, CustomClass.class);
List<CustomClass> beanList = (List<CustomClass>)objectMapper.readValue(stringBean, customClassCollection);
```

Comment: I figured it out, and then I saw your answer. I will accept this as the correct answer since It's actually what I was trying to do.

Comment: Excellent example of a custom deserializer, and how to manipulate it to deserialize a list of JSON objects.

Answer (score 11):

I worked it out by adding a custom deserializer to an attribute in my model class and using JsonDeserialize annotation's `contentUsing()` method, like so:

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
private List<CustomClass> customClassObjList;
```

where MyCustomDeserializer class is a custom Jackson JSON deserializer defined as:

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<CustomClass> {
    
    @Override
    public CustomClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean Jackson can automatically deserialize List<CustomClass> even though you have only defined the deserialize for the individual CustomClass object?

Comment: Yes. The trick is to use `contentUsing` not `using`

Comment: how do I use `contentusing` for a custom deserializer which is registered via SimpleModule 



`SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();`
`module.addDeserializer(MyCustomDeserializer.class, CustomClass);`
    
`ObjectMapper objectMapper  = new ObjectMapper();`
`objectMapper.registerModule(module);`

Answer (score 2):

These two lines will just do enough.

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) objectMapper.readTree(stringBean);
List<CustomClass> response = objectMapper.convertValue(arrayNode, List.class);
```

Thank me later!