# Convert List<List<TextValue>> to List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have this output JSON.  It comes from this type
`List<List<TextValue>>`
TextValue class is String text, String value.

```
"data": [
  [
    {
      "text": "DescCode",
      "value": "01"
    },
    {
      "text": "DescName",
      "value": "Description 1"
    },
    {
      "text": "SecondCode",
      "value": "01"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "DescCode",
      "value": "02"
    },
    {
      "text": "DescName",
      "value": "Description 2"
    },
    {
      "text": "SecondCode",
      "value": "02"
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to transform it to this JSON out.
which I believe would be this object setup.
`List<Map<String, String>>`

```
"data": [
    {
      "DescCode": "01",
      "DescName": "Description 1",
      "SecondCode": "01"
    },      
    {
      "DescCode":"02",
      "DescName":"Description 2",
      "SecondCode":"02"
    }
]
```

My JSON is created automatically by my Spring REST controller so I really just need the Java object, Json is just for Reference.
Am I off base with this?  `List<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: Hi, you could use the stream `map` method to transform the inner `List` to a `Map`. Or if parsing from JSON a [custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176607/custom-deserialization-of-list-using-jackson/34179679) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is nested list of `TextValue` objects.

```
List<List<TextValue>> list = List.of(
        List.of(new TextValue("DescCode", "01"),
                new TextValue("DescName", "Description 1"),
                new TextValue("SecondCode", "01")),
        List.of(new TextValue("DescCode", "02"),
                new TextValue("DescName", "Description 2"),
                new TextValue("SecondCode", "02")));
```

And this basically streams the inner lists and then streams each of those to create a map with the specified keys and values.  The maps are then collected into a list.

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfMaps = list.stream()
       .map(lst->lst.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(TextValue::getText, TextValue::getValue)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

listOfMaps.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
{DescName=Description 1, DescCode=01, SecondCode=01}
{DescName=Description 2, DescCode=02, SecondCode=02}
```

The TextValue class.

```
class TextValue {
    String text;
    String value;
    
    public TextValue(String text, String value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s,  %s", text, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Loading my `List<Map<String, String>>` datatype was the anwser.  I thought I was going to need to use some fancy stream processing but that was not necessary.  Nested loops with the right objects got me there.

```
List<Map<String,String>> test = new ArrayList<>();
    String xmlResponseStringDesc = httpUtility.DoHttpRequest(url);
    Document doc = XmlHelper.convertStringToXMLDocument(xmlResponseStringDesc);
    NodeList nodes= doc.getElementsByTagName("DescData");
    for(int x=0;x<nodes.getLength();x++){
        NodeList nodeListInner = nodes.item(x).getChildNodes();
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int y=0;y<nodeListInner.getLength();y++){
            Node nodeInner = nodeListInner.item(y);
            if(nodeInner.getTextContent().trim().equals("")){
                continue;
            }                
            map.put(nodeInner.getNodeName()
               ,nodeInner.getTextContent());
        }
        test.add(map);
    }
```