# deserialize List of Enum in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-deserialization

I developed an enum class of the type:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomEnumDeserializer.class)
public enum Month {

    JANUARY(1, "January"),
    FEBRUARY(2, "February"),
    MARCH(3, "March"),
    APRIL(4, "April"),
    MAY(5, "May"),
    JUNE(6, "June"),
    JULY(7, "July"),
    AUGUST(8, "August"),
    SEPTEMBER(9, "September"),
    OCTOBER(10, "October"),
    NOVEMBER(11, "November"),
    DECEMBER(12, "December");

    public final int code;
    public final String lowerName;


    private Month(
            int code,
            String lowerName
    ) {
        this.code = code;
        this.lowerName = lowerName;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getLowerName() {
        return lowerName;
    }

}
```

I built a CustomEnumDeserializer of the type:

```
public class CustomEnumDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Month> {

    public CustomEnumDeserializer() {
        super(Month.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Month deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        String lowerName = node.get("lowerName").asText();
        int code = node.get("code").asInt();

        for (Month month : Month.values()) {

            if (month.getLowerName().equalsIgnoreCase(lowerName) || month.getCode() == code) {
                return month;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

what I want is for the user to be able to use as input either the months expressed according to whole numbers from 1 to 12, or directly using the names by ingnoring the case (uppercase, lowercase or mixed):

```
{
"period": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

or

```
{
"period": ["january", "february", "March"]
}
```

or

```
{
"period": ["january", "FEBRUARY", 3]
}
```

Also, I am handling the error with a message if a used parameter (e.g., 13) is inserted in the request.

I tried to follow various examples like the one proposed by [Eugen Paraschiv](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums) but honestly there are some shortcomings and I always get the following error (due that I use an enum list?).

```
2023-12-13T22:26:00.663+01:00  WARN 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.asText()" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(String)" is null]
```

some UPDATE using [1, 2, 3] as input in period

[image]

Comment: I assume you have to use `or` instead of `and`. And since you have json with single field which is array you have to call in first. `node.get("period")`. Also generic type have to be `Collection<Month>`

Comment: yes I use || (not &&) in the line "month.getLowerName().equalsIgnoreCase(lowerName) || month.getCode() == code". The error is generated by String lowerName = node.get("lowerName").asText(); when I use as input [1, 2, 3] for example

Comment: You need to drop a level below in tree to begin parse array content. [1,2,3] is not your input as I see its a content of the field `period` which you have to `get`. The reason of `null` is that it's looking for the field `lowerName` in json on the same level where `period` is. You can't call this names you will have to classify (or map) values of array on fly, when you will iterate through them.

Comment: I updated the question but it's the first time I am working with this problem and I am honestly lost

Comment: This might help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176607/custom-deserialization-of-list-using-jackson`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need custom mapper at all. Try this, maybe it will help you to move on in understanding of json structure.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String raw = "{\n" +
                "\"period\": [\"january\", \"FEBRUARY\", 3]\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Data data = mapper.readValue(raw, Data.class);
        System.out.println("data = " + data);
        System.out.println("data.getMapped() = " + data.getMapped());


    }


    public static class Data {

        List<Object> period;

        public Data() {
        }

        public List<Object> getPeriod() {
            return period;
        }

        public void setPeriod(List<Object> period) {
            this.period = period;
        }

        public List<Month> getMapped() {
                return period.stream().map(o -> {
                    if(o instanceof String s){
                        return Month.getMe(s);
                    } else if(o instanceof Integer i){
                        return Month.getMe(i);
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse");
                }}).toList();
            }
        }


    enum Month {
        JANUARY(1, "January"),
        FEBRUARY(2, "February"),
        MARCH(3, "March"),
        APRIL(4, "April"),
        MAY(5, "May"),
        JUNE(6, "June"),
        JULY(7, "July"),
        AUGUST(8, "August"),
        SEPTEMBER(9, "September"),
        OCTOBER(10, "October"),
        NOVEMBER(11, "November"),
        DECEMBER(12, "December");

        public final int code;
        public final String lowerName;


        Month(int code,
              String lowerName) {
            this.code = code;
            this.lowerName = lowerName;
        }

        public static Month getMe(Integer i) {
            return Month.values()[i - 1];
        }

        public static Month getMe(String i) {
            return Arrays.stream(Month.values()).filter(e -> e.lowerName.equalsIgnoreCase(i))
                    .findAny().get();
        }
    }

}
```

An elegant solution, given that the types are mixed, is hardly possible here, perhaps the best that came to mind from the rough ones.